# HTTParty giving 401 using http basic authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, sinatra, httparty

I have two applications. One contains an API (Rails) and the second (Sinatra) is a test application to check if the API is working correctly.
In the test application I can get all of the information provided by my API using HTTParty. However, when I try to add http basic authentication in the API application, 
the test application always gets a 401 error.

In the controller which provides the API I have written

```
http_basic_authenticate_with name: "admin", password: "admin"
```

In my test application I have written

```
authenticate = {name: "admin", password: "admin"}
options = {query: {username: params[:username], email: params[:email]}, 
         basic_auth: authenticate}
response = HTTParty.get('http://localhost:3000/search.json', options)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your key for the username is incorrect:

```
authenticate = {:username => 'admin', :password => 'admin'}
```

This should work

Comment: No, `username` is part of a search scope where I search for users. `name` is the name, `admin` in this case, to authenticate to the API.

Comment: HTTParty expects the username for basic http to be set by the key `username`. Have a look at [this example](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/twitter.rb)